# HTML - formatting off when resizing browser

Tags: html

I am very new to HTML and I'm having some difficulties with the formatting when resizing the browser window. When the browser is large I have an image floating on the left then text on the right. However, when the browser is smaller the text wraps around weirdly. Ideally I want the text to move underneath the images when resizing the browser, but I'm not sure how to go about it. The best that I could do was set an absolute div for the entire thing to create a scroll on the side to maintain the formatting. The problem is, this is on a larger website that modifies the formatting when the browser size is reduced so it still looks weird.

Any help would be appreciated! And I apologize in advance for my messy code.

```
<body>
  <div style="min-width: 960px; margin: 0 auto;">
    <p><strong>Why re-invent the wheel? Here are existing resources both on and offline
    that offer support and services we think are helpful.</strong></p>

    <p><img alt="" src=
    "/sites/default/files/u32/Screen%20Shot%202013-11-08%20at%203.57.06%20PM.png" style=
    "width: 1000px; height: 300px;" /></p>

    <div class="outercontainer">
      <div class="innercontainer">
        <div h3="" style="position:relative">
          &nbsp;

          <div>
            <a href=
            "http://www.walkalong.ca/links/professional-health-care-facilities"><img alt=
            "" src="/sites/default/files/u29/Link1new.png" style=
            "opacity: 0.9; width: 385px; height: 171px; float: left; border-width: 0px; border-style: solid; margin-left: 120px; margin-right: 10px;" /></a>
          </div>

          <div>
            <span style="line-height: 1.6em;">&nbsp;</span>
          </div>

          <div>
            <p class="p1">&nbsp;</p>

            <h3 class="p1"><span class="s1">Search lists of health care,
            psychology&nbsp;</span><br />
            <span style="line-height: 1.6em;">and counselling directories <a href=
            "http://www.walkalong.ca/links/professional-health-care-facilities">here</a></span></h3>
          </div>

          <p>&nbsp;</p>

          <p>&nbsp;</p>

          <h3><a href="http://www.walkalong.ca/links/support-tools"><img alt="" src=
          "/sites/default/files/u29/Link2new.png" style=
          "opacity: 0.9; width: 362px; height: 159px; float: right; border-width: 0px; border-style: solid; margin-left: 90px; margin-right: 90px;" /></a></h3>

          <p>&nbsp;</p>

          <h3 align="right">Find a wide range of support tools that&nbsp;<br />
          <span style="line-height: 1.6em;">offer one-on-one conversations <a href=
          "http://www.walkalong.ca/links/support-tools">here</a></span></h3>

          <p>&nbsp;</p>

          <p>&nbsp;</p>

          <p><a href="http://www.walkalong.ca/links/related-resources"><img alt="" src=
          "/sites/default/files/u29/Link3revision.png" style=
          "width: 372px; height: 159px; float: left; margin: 10px 10px 10px 140px;" /></a></p>

          <p>&nbsp;</p>

          <p>&nbsp;</p>

          <h3 class="p1"><span class="s1">Find additional resources on mental<br />
          health for all of your needs <a href=
          "http://www.walkalong.ca/links/related-resources">here</a></span></h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: do you have a parent div which contains all the elements?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are talking about?

```
<style>
.left{
    float:left;
    width:300px;    
}
.left img{
    width:300px;
    height:auto;    
}
</style> 


<div class="left">
    <img src="http://www.newyorker.com/online/blogs/photobooth/NASAEarth-01.jpg"/>
</div>
<div class="left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adi Lorem ipsum dolor sit 
    amet, ctetur adi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adi. Lorem
    ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adi.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adi
</div>
```

Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/hxMK4/